# Truncating long part titles in Legrand Orange template

Tags: formatting, titles, titlesec

I am new to Latex.

I am using the [Legrand Orange book template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book).
Some of my part titles are too long and should be truncated for two lines.
Any idea how I can make it wrap the title?

Thanks.

[image]

**Update**: The following file of code treats the title: `\node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north east) {\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{red}{\strut #2}}; % Part title.`

However I couldn't find a way to wrap the text.

Comment: Welcome. // Kindly see my answer below (in a few moments).

Answer (score 2):

That's a tough one for a beginner.

---

**#1 Observations**

You can have a closer look into it via [overleaf](https://plates/the-legrand-orange-book-template-english/jtctyfmnpppc).

Doing so *(Version 2.1.1 (14/2/16))* shows two important lines of code. First, it's based on the `book`-class:

- `\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations`

Second, there are now redefinitions of styles etc. which you usually put into the documents preamble. Instead they moved out all those statements into:

- `\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template`

BUT leave no hint, where to find `"structure"` or `command.tex` . Inspecting them isn't needed, but would be interesting to know, to see, WHAT they did to introduce layout adjustments. E.g.:

- did they do it via some packages from [ctan](https://www.ctan.org)?
- did they follow their approach of title-page design using `tikz`?
- and so on.

So the answer to your question "how to have a longer part title" depends on said approach.

LaTeX-wise after that analysis you'd put some `\renewcommand`s here:

```
\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

% <<< enter \renew-commands as needed
% <<< or delegate them to a file to \input{} as shown above

\begin{document}
```

~~

---

**#2 What can you do?**

For the moment just ignore the problem and continue entering your content. Return to it later, once you acquired more experience with LaTeX or more answers drop in to your question.

Also consider coming up with shorter titles.

To learn LaTeX get some introduction, like a book from your library, or this one online, the [Wikibook on Latex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX).

If no more answers come, search this site. e.g. via:

- `Related` links to the right of your question
- search terms like [orange command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=orange%20command) or [orange part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=orange%20part)

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.
I have programming background,  so I think that I have some potential to succeed with LaTex.
I am using Version 3.1 (February 18, 2022) of the Legrand Orange Book.
You can find it here: [link]( https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=https://www.latextemplates.com/actions/action_download_template?template=legrand-orange-book-overleaf)
The styling rules are in a separate file: “LegrandOrangeBook.cls”.
The relevant styles are can be found in rows 121:132

Comment: The following file of code treats the title: \node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north east) {\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{red}{\strut #2}}; % Part title. However I couldn't find a way to wrap the text.

Comment: The best place for this kind of comment is your question, see above.

Answer (score 1):

Mathias Legrand proposed to use 'parbox' and it solves the issue.

in the .cls file, replace the statement:

```
\node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north east){\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\strut #2}}; % Part title
```

by

```
\node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, xshift=-\Gm@rmargin, yshift=-\Gm@tmargin] at (current page.north east) {\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\strut #2}}}; % Part title
```